# Django, execute templatetag before rendering template

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that is somewhat of a webshop. In the app, POST is handled in a templatetag called posthandler.py like this

```
{% load posthandler %}
{% posthandler %}
```

In the index.html that is always loaded. After that, in the file there is the primary bit like this

```
{% block primary %}{% endblock %}
```

Now, that primary bit display a value, stock, that might have been adjusted in the posthandler bit. Meaning, the value can be stale. This has the effect of a person clicking on a item, adding it to their order list, but the page needing two refreshes before the stock value is correctly reflecting the value in the DB.

I think this is because of the order that the templatetags are handled, something like this;

1. User clicks button to add to orderlist
2. The page reloads via the view, first rendering the stock value in index.html based on what is currently in the DB
3. The posthandler.py runs, substracting one from the stock, so the DB is now up to date.
4. The page displays, with the wrong number, since that value was retrieved from the DB before it was adjusted.

I would think to handle the post in the view, but I want the same posthandler to run on all the different pages, so that doesn't seem the way to go. Is there a better way to do this? Or, can I get the primary block to only execute after the templatetags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing forms in templates is indeed a design mistake. Using [middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/) should suit your needs.

Another solution would be to create a View mixin, and make all your views inherit from that mixin. But using a middleware should be better.

However, why don't you have a single page that handles this POST request, and redirects to the accurate page after form processing?

Comment: I don't have such a page because I didn't really think about that. I'll look into the middlewares.

Comment: Having a single page dedicated to receiving and handling this POST request seems like the way to go. It will be much clearer, easier, and will save the overhead of checking the request method and, in the case it is POST, checking that the submitted form is the one you want to process.

Comment: I kinda want the process to be transparant. Perhaps later even without reloads. The middleware solution you suggested works fine so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you are doing stuff in a templatetag that should not be done there. I've never read about a restriction towards that end, but I think conceptually, template tags should be stateless and not modify the database content.

To do the required work in your views without logic duplication, you can use class based views and have them inherit from a common Mixin class where you implement the data modification, or decorate them with a common decorator and implement the data modification in that decorator.

But if the modification should be done for *all* views, a middleware as [Antoine suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704798/674064) is probably the way to go.